# Converting java Stream to Set

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a 2-D array of ints, and a method with an argument that points to one of its rows. I want to return a `Set` over the elements of that row that are non-zero, and I want to do it without a for loop. So this is what I have tried:

```
public Set<Integer> getNeighbors(int node) {
        assert node >= 0 && node < numNodes : "getNeighbors(): Invalid node parameter given: " + node + ".";
       return Arrays.stream(matrix[node]).filter(n->n>0).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a compile-time error which is a bit hard to parse:

[image: A Screenshot from my IDE]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return Arrays.stream(matrix[node])
             .filter(n -> n > 0)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

will do it. The `.boxed()` bit is the relevant part.

Comment: Ah yes, the boxing to an `Integer` needed to be done. Thanks, accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create  `Set` with int primitives, ([`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) "*returns a sequential `IntStream` with the specified `Array` as its source*") and a `Set<int>` is not allowed. You want to add in a `boxed()` to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
public Set<Integer> getNeighbors(int node) {
    assert node >= 0 && node < numNodes : "getNeighbors(): Invalid node parameter given: " + node + ".";
    return Arrays.stream(matrix[node])   //IntStream
                 .filter(n->n>0)   
                 .boxed()                //Convert to Stream<Integer>
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```